# parsing odd json array

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

The json data I need to serialize is an array of point which looks like this:

```
"coordinates":
        [
            [
                [
                    [6.64215,53.36364],
                    [6.64215,53.36364]
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

But I do not know how the object representation should look like.
In other words what way should I build my classes? 
(C# using `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`)

Comment: You should consider switching to JSON.NET. JavaScriptSerialized is outdated. It has a successor: DataContractSerializer, but even official MS products like WebAPI use JSON.NET. It's powerful and works like a charm. You could even deserialize this array as an  ExpandoObject and you wouldn't need to think "what type": just a dynamic type!

Answer (score 0):

```
var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer()
          .Deserialize<Dictionary<string,List<List<List<List<double>>>>>>(json);

double d01 = dict["coordinates"][0][0][0][0];
double d02 = dict["coordinates"][0][0][0][1];
```

:)))

Answer (score -1):

the correct answer seems to be:

```
public double[][][][] coordinates { get; set; }
```

Thank you for your help!